# ¿Como elimino el fondo blanco de una tabla? Foundation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bueno mi problema es que eh agregado foundation rails a mi proyecto que esta creado en ruby on rails y pues quise crear una pequeña tabla, pero dicha tabla al crear me pone un fondo blanco, yo lo que quiero realizar es que mi tabla sea transparente sin fondo de ningún color.

ya lo intente poniéndole una clase y asignándole propiedades pero no funciona, tambien le agregue el estilo de manera directa, elimine los cookies por si acaso pero sigue sin cambiar de color, solo cambia de tamaño.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo .css

```
.tabla {
    width:80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

archivo .html.erb

```
<table border="2"  class="tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>Film Affinity</td>
    <td><%= image_tag "film_affinity.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>IMDB</td>
    <td><%= image_tag "imdb.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Sensa Cine</td>
    <td><%= image_tag "sensacine.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: que tipo de css agregaste? puedes dejar el codigo?

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: ¿has intentado `background-color:transparent !important;`?

Comment: @Rene Limon ya lo aplique, pero  aun asi no me quita el fondo

Answer (score 0):

Te falta también modificar los css de los elementos dentro de la tabla.

```css
#rojo{
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.tabla {
    width:80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color:transparent;
}
.tabla tbody {
    background-color:transparent;
}
.tabla tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id='rojo'>
  <table border="2" class="tabla">
    <tr>
      <td>Film Affinity</td>
      <td>
        <%= image_tag "film_affinity.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IMDB</td>
      <td>
        <%= image_tag "imdb.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sensa Cine</td>
      <td>
        <%= image_tag "sensacine.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

A futuro, puedes revisar por tu cuenta que estilos aplican a cada elemento en chrome haciendo clic derecho y elegir "Inspeccionar". Ahí te saldrá una sección donde en la izquierda puedes ver los elementos de tu html y a la derecha los estilos css que aplican para el elemento que elijas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]